# Is projection to quotient space an open map?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T:(V,\|\cdot\|_V) \rightarrow (W, \|\cdot\|_W)$ be a continuous linear map between normed vector spaces. Then the kernel $U=\ker T$ is closed and we can consider the projection map $P:V\rightarrow V/U$ where $V/U$ is endowed with the norm: $$\|[v]\|_{V/U} := \inf_{x \in [v]} \|x\|_V$$

My question is: Is $P$ an open map? i.e it sends open sets in $V$ to that of $V/U$.

This is my attempt: Let $S$ be an open set in $V$, we claim that $P(S)$ is open. Choose a class $[s]\in P(S)$ where $s\in S$. Since $S$ is open then there exists an open ball $B(s,r)$ contained within $S$. I claim that $B([s],r)$ is in $P(S)$. Choose any $[v]\in B([s],r)$, then note that:

$$\|[v-s]\|_{V/U} =\inf_{x \in [v-s]}\|x\|_V \le\|v-s\|_V$$ This is where the problem arises. I am unable to show that the above inequality is less than $r$. (If I can do so then we are done.) Any tips given would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[v] \in B([s],r)$ implies that $\|v-s-u\| <r$ for some $u \in U$. By an argument similar to what you have done you get $\|[v-s]\|=\|[v-s-u]\|\leq \|v-s-u\| <r$.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. So from here we can conclude $v-u \in B(s,r) \subset S$ and so $[v-u]=[v]\in P(S)$. Is this correct?

Comment: @thedilated Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score -1):

By the Open Mapping Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(functional_analysis)), a linear countinuous surjective map is open.

Comment: Hi. Yes I am aware of this theorem but I would like to show it via the method I've written above.

Comment: The open mapping theorem requires both the domain space and codomain space to be *complete*. For general normed spaces, the result doesn't hold.